# Firebase messages not receiving after device being turned off for a few days (is there a topic subscription lifetime or something?)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I thought firebase messages should be stored for up to 4 weeks by default, however when i have my phone turned off for a few days, say 3 days or 6 days nothing is coming in, not even things from half an hour ago or something.

Is there a lifetime to topic subscriptions or something? since these messages are sent to a topic rather then to tokens.

I haven't tested it with sending messages to tokens yet, it is for a shoutbox from a website which i have made into a android app.

Is this due to it being send to a topic and there is a lifetime of the subscription to it?

is there a way to change that, or should i just loop through the tokens i have stored in my db at the website whenever a shout is send and send it to all?

Comment: check your send notification code, if you set time_to_live paramater. Remove that if exists

Comment: @DivyeshPatel the only fields that are set are to and data, the headers are authorisation key and content-type, that's all.

Comment: did you  check in other devices?

Comment: I only tested it on one samsung galaxy s4, if i just have my phone off over night everything is fine, but after a day or 2/3 nothing comes in only things that are being send since i started my phone up, which makes me suspect that my subscription to the topic is cancelled cause firebase hasn't heared from me in a while.

Comment: You have to conatct firebase team, they resolve your issue for sure.

Comment: It's hard to comment on anything without knowing anything other than the scenario. Could you post more details like some code snippets related to FCM? How you're sending the message (app server or through console)? Device details I think might be heplful too (os version, etc.) But to answer the question with topic subscriptions, AFAIK, there isn't any expirations. You should go ahead and try it out first if it's the same behavior when you send it via the actual token before reaching out to Firebase Support. The more details you can give them, the better.